# "Table is mutating" error occurs when inserting into a table that has an after insert trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I'm trying to create an after insert trigger that inserts the details of a purchase made into a purchases log table and, as well, update the total cost column in the purchases table to add GCT of 16.5% to the total. The two tables have these columns:

```
    CREATE TABLE purchases 
    (
        p_Id        INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
        product     VARCHAR(25) ,
        quantity    INTEGER     ,
        unit_Cost   FLOAT       ,
        total_Cost  FLOAT       
    );

    CREATE TABLE purchases_log
    (
        event_Date      DATE        ,
        p_Id            INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY,
        description     varchar(75) 
    );
```

The trigger I'm trying to use is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PURCHASES_AUDIT
AFTER INSERT ON purchases
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE TAX FLOAT;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO purchases_log
VALUES(SYSDATE,:NEW.p_Id,'INSERT INTO PURCHASES TABLE');
tax := 1.165;
UPDATE purchases SET total_Cost = quantity * unit_Cost;
UPDATE purchases SET total_Cost = total_Cost*tax;
END PURCHASES_AUDIT;
/
```

however when trying to run an insert on the purchase table oracle gives me this error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table PURCHASES is mutating, trigger/function may
not see it
ORA-06512: at "PURCHASES_AUDIT", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PURCHASES_AUDIT'
```

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Don't `update` the table on which the trigger is defined.

It sounds like you want a before insert trigger, not an after insert trigger, that modifies the `:new` pseudo-record.  If I understand your intention correctly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PURCHASES_AUDIT
  BEFORE INSERT ON purchases
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  TAX FLOAT;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO purchases_log
    VALUES(SYSDATE,:NEW.p_Id,'INSERT INTO PURCHASES TABLE');
  tax := 1.165;
  :new.total_Cost = :new.quantity * :new.unit_Cost * tax;
END PURCHASES_AUDIT;
```

As an aside, do you really, really want to use a `float` rather than a `number`?  Do you fully understand the approximate nature of floating point numbers?  I've never come across anyone working with money that wanted to use a `float`.

Comment: Thank you, and pardon me but I'm a bit of a novice. I actually don't fully understand the difference between a float and a number. I'll do my research on the two variable types for future use though.

Comment: @tajay - You can real What Every Developer Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html  But to summarize, float is an approximate data type.  1 * 0.9 may be 0.90000000000001.  Or it may be 0.89999999996.  It'll be close to the correct value but computers can't represent floating point values exactly so you'll accumulate errors.  That's not a problem if you're doing scientific calculations where you are accumulating an error term anyway.  I've never seen anyone happy to have monetary values be imprecise though.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a point of clarification: before triggers allow you to update the :new values, after triggers do not. The :new values if after triggers will always contain the final value.